# Scala - why actor model is an example of mixing OO and functional programming?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, actor

To quote from [Chapter 1 of Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/a-scalable-language.html):

> ... in Scala a function value is an object. Function types are classes
>   that can be inherited by subclasses. This might seem nothing more than
>   an academic nicety, but it has deep consequences for scalability. In
>   fact the actor concept shown previously could not have been
>   implemented without this unification of functions and objects.

I don't quite understand why the author said actor concept cannot be implemented without unifying OO and functional programming. Could someone explain?

As an example, here is a simple Scala actor implementing a checksum calculator service:

```
actor { 
    var sum = 0
    loop {
      receive {
        case Data(bytes)       => sum += hash(bytes)
        case GetSum(requester) => requester ! sum
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The actor model was first implemented in Erlang, which was most definitely not an OO language. I believe the author is only referring to the particular implementation discussed in the book.

Comment: The "selling" point of the author is that thanks to having functions as first class values within the language (ie. the ability of *constructing* and *manipulating* functions like any other value in the language), reimplementing the Erlang actors concept with close to identical *syntax* and *semantic* was feasible, whereas without first class functions, it would have been impossible.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner: that's not true. The Actor Model was invented by Carl Hewitt in 1973 and the first Actor Language was PLASMA, also created by Carl Hewitt in 1975. Erlang was created in the 80s. In fact, the designers of Erlang didn't actually know about the Actor Model until well after they designed it. Only when Joe Armstrong wrote his thesis did he realize that they had independently re-invented the Actor Model.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner: Also, since *the* defining concept of OO is message-passing, Erlang most definitely *is* an OO language. In fact, Joe Armstrong, one of the designers of Erlang, said that of all todays mainstream languages, Erlang is probably the *most* object-oriented; and I have to agree.

Comment: He doesn't say that the actor concept cannot be implemented. He says that the *specific* concept "shown previously" cannot be implemented. He also doesn't say that it cannot be implemented without unifying OO and functional programming, he says it cannot be implemented without unifying functions and objects.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Your knowledge of the history of programming is impressive, but I am going to have to disagree on the definition of OO. Defining OO as message-passing would allow even C and Haskell to qualify. OO for me is inheritance and the particular kind of polymorphism it allows, i.e. virtual method calls or similar functionality in a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I don't quite understand why the author said actor concept cannot be implemented without unifying OO and functional programming."

The authors did *not* say ["Functional Programming"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) in that quote (although Scala does take a number of such concepts as the chapter address later on), but rather..

> .. In fact the actor concept shown previously could not have been implemented without this *unification of functions and objects*.

The major implication of this is that functions are [First-Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) and as such can be passed around as any other type of value - this in turn makes functions suitable for callbacks, such as "reactions".

However, the example shown really does not show "unification of functions and objects" well at all, even if they are unified underneath (even the pattern matching yields a function). As such, the quote should be taken more as a bait on a fishing line..

> [Scala is a] language that grows on you

Comment: He doesn't say it in the quote, but if you read a couple of lines above it in the text, he clearly means it.